# Turning on Output_Buffering creates 404 errors on random pages

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, http-status-code-404, output-buffering

I've been playing with `output_buffering` in php (confirmed by `phpinfo()`) and I just discovered that upon turning it on, I will start getting random 404 errors on my pages, but the page content loads fine and everything looks ok.

This only happens on my production site. PHP 5.5.35, Apache/2.4.18 (Unix). I have no idea where this 404 is being sent from. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be happening, or what I can search for on my server to fix it?

These are my response headers in case that's at all relevant:

```
Cache-Control:s-maxage=10
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:13021
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 02 Feb 2018 18:31:59 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=96
Server:Apache
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.35
```

EDIT: 
I discovered that this issue only happens on pages on which I am loading 'recent posts' from a Wordpress instance. It's not really an option for me to remove this little widget but I assume there's a reason behind setting a 404 header. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is technically OK to have a page with response code = 404 and have (potentially useful) content (i) could you tell us what is the expected resut...404 or 200 (ii) Could you confirm if the behavior is random or predictable?

Comment: I expect a 200, and the behavior is..odd. I will sometimes see pages with with a 404 error and hard refreshing does nothing - the error comes back. Then I'll come in the next morning and every page that was not working will come back with a 200 status. So I guess unpredictable, but not from one second to the next.

Comment: Strange. Anyway, check PHP error logs for "cannot  modify header" or similar. Post any errors that you find.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening is that your code is issuing 404s in some cases regardless of whether output buffering is on or off; but when output buffering is *off* the header fails to be set because it has already been written generating a warning like this one:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /file.php:20) in /file.php on line 100

So you can only see the 404 when output buffering is *on* which enables you to set headers at any point before the buffers are written to output.

Comment: This is possible, but the only times I receive that error is when my recent posts Wordpress widget attempts to set cache-control headers. I can't imagine why Wordpress would send a 404, and from what point in the code it would originate from. Do you have any recommendations for finding out?

Comment: Set an error handler to catch warnings and see if this is the case, if there is a warning like the one i'm suggesting you message will have file name and line number.

Comment: Maybe you can send all warning to a log file https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: I've definitely gotten the "cannot modify header information" error continually, but it refers back to the wordpress functions.php file for setting nocache headers. I think you're right though, something here is sending a 404 and it's more of a Wordpress question than an output_buffering question.